# listbox items not displaying properly

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listbox and a ListItem object which I am adding to the listbox so that I can retrieve a value from the selected item which is different then the displayed member.

```
class ListItem
{
    public string DisplayMember;
    public string ValueMember;
    public ListItem(string n,string v){
         DisplayMember = n;
         ValueMember = v;
    }
}


public CompareTimeFramesForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();           
    listBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("# of Bookings", null));
    listBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("People", "guaranteed_count"));
}
```

This is a winform FYI. 
The problem I am having is the item shown in the actual listbox has the object rather then the string I would like to be displayed in the first argument of the ListItem constructor.
It looks like `Bookings.Helpers.ListItem` rather then "# of Bookings"

In the designer I changed the displayMember property to DisplayMember and its not working.

Comment: Side note: please avoid adding tags to title. Also "Visual Studio" is does not seem to apply to your question (either title or tag) as you don't seem to be building VS plugin of any kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:

> When an object is being added to the ListBox, the control uses the text defined in the ToString method of the object unless a member name within the object is specified in the DisplayMember property.

`ListBox` will convert item to string calling `ToString()`. In your case you just need to change your `ListItem` class like this:

```
class ListItem
{
    public string DisplayMember;
    public string ValueMember;

    public ListItem(string n,string v) {
         DisplayMember = n;
         ValueMember = v;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return DisplayMember;
    }
}
```

As alternative you can se the `DisplayMember` property (in designer or with code) to use your property (you called that property `DisplayMember` but its name is free because it must be specified and it doesn't use any convention):

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayMember";
```

Answer (score -1):

try this it should work for you!

```
class ListItem
{
public string DisplayMember;
public string ValueMember;
 public ListItem(string n,string v){
     DisplayMember = n;
     ValueMember = v;
 }
```

}

```
public CompareTimeFramesForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();           
    listBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("# of Bookings", null).DisplayMember);
    listBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("People", "guaranteed_count").DisplayMember);
}
```

Comment: This will only make the string value selectable and not the ListItem object.