# Generic objects managed automatically by a ListBox control?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

All of the [examples](http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-listbox.htm) I've seen using the `ListBox` control use `string` data, or a `List<string>` datasource.

What are the basic requirements for a new class if it is to serve as the **datasource** for a WinForms `ListBox` control?

Comment: Not a duplicate but it shows what you have to do (very little): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619319/listbox-items-not-displaying-properly/24619388#24619388

Comment: If you really want generic items (bitmaps, strings, etc) you will need to make it owner draw.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I'd like it to work with something like `List<MyClass<T>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd do something along the lines of a List of ListBoxItem< T >, and then the ListBoxItem would look something like this:

```
public class ListBoxItem<T>
{
    private Func<T, string> _getText;

    public T Item { get; private set; }

    public ListBoxItem<T>(T item, Func<T, string> getText)
    {
        Item = item;
        _getText = getText;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _getText(Item);
    }
}
```

Then whenever the ListBoxItem is shown in the ListBox view, the framework itself will call ToString, and you'd have specified how it should show.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Why would you want a MyClass<T>? Why not just use the T type in the ListBoxItem? But assuming you need to have T wrapped in MyClass, then yes, that is what I'd do.

Comment: I appreciate how your approach lends itself to code re-use, but would you recommend another layer of abstraction ala `List<ListBoxItem<MyClass<T>>>`?

Comment: No, I wouldn't recommend the MyClass layer. Imo that seems unnecessary, unless there's a special reason for having it there.

Comment: I'm probably not using generics correctly, but my code is patterned after an API that uses `Class<TDepth> where TDepth : struct` and TDepth is not truly generic but restricted to a list of types UInt, Int, Double, etc. I'm not sure how that can be done in a better way so I've just followed the parent design.

Comment: The magical and wonderful thing about generics is that they are truly generic. If you do not restrict the T to a specific type, you can use any type you want. The tricky thing is, you'll need to know how to handle them. In my example, I redirect that responsibility to where you actually call the constructor, because at this level in the code, you know what type T is. All in all, spend a few hours on reading and messing with generics, and I'm sure you'll be fine.